# Hidding datatable column and column data dynamically in Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to hide a column and its data in data table if some condition is true in J query. I am able to hide the column using below code whenever needed(condition is true).

```
{
                            'targets': [1],
                            'render': function (data, type, row, meta){
                                var student= $("#studentName").val();
                                if(student==''){
                                    return '<a href="URL?student='+row.student+'">'+row.student+'</a>';
                                }else{
                                    table.columns([1]).visible(false);
                                }
                            }
                        },
```

But it throws below warning while loading data. If I click OK to warning, data is displayed as intended(column and its contents are not displayed)

> "DataTables warning: table id={id} - Requested unknown parameter
>   '{parameter}' for row {row-index}, column{column-index}"

Comment: Please show your entire dataTables initialisation code.

Comment: Please provide entire DataTable code otherwise is't not possible to help you.

Comment: please provide proper information

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks for replying. I figured it out. basically error comes if table column headers count does not match with data columns to be rendered. I am putting solution as separate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning comes if table column headers count does not match with data columns to be renderedSince I am hiding one column, Now No of column headers are 1 more than data columns, so If I set default content of missing column data to empty, this warning will go away.I did it like below

```
"{"data": "studentName",
                    "defaultContent": ""},
                .........
                ],"
```

Now if student Name column is visible, data table will be drawn as usual. If student Name column is hidden, default content will be set.

Complete data table components are as below.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "pagingType": "simple",
        "sDom" : '<"top"lp>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
        "ajax": {
               url: 'JSONURL.json',
               dataType: 'json',
               type: 'GET',
               data: function ( d ){
                   d.param1= $("#studentName").val(),

                },
            },
        "columns": [
            {"data": ""},
            {"data": "studentName",
                "defaultContent": ""},
            .........
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                         {
                            'targets': [1],
                            'render': function (data, type, row, meta){
                                var student = $("#studentName").val();
                                if(student==''){
                                    return '<a href="URL?student='+row.studentName">'+row.studentName+'</a>';
                                }else{
                                    table.columns([1]).visible(false);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Show **columns** with default return statement and then conditions in **columnDefs**

```
"columns": [
        {"data": ""},
        {"data": "studentName"},{"data": "mobile"},
],
"columnDefs": [
        {
            'targets': [3],
            'render': function (data, type, row, meta){
                if(row.studentName != undefined){
                    return row.studentName;  
                }else{
                    table.columns([3]).visible(false);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            'targets': [4],
            'render': function (data, type, row, meta){
                if(row.mobile != undefined){
                    return row.mobile;  
                }else{
                    table.columns([4]).visible(false);
                }
            }
        }
```

]

Answer (score 0):

```
"initComplete": function (settings) {
                var api = this.api();
                for (var i = 0; i < api.rows({ page: 'current' }).data().length; ++i) 
                {
                    if(api.rows({ page: 'current' }).data()[i].Status == "VISIBILITY_CONDITION")
                        {
                            tab.columns([9]).visible(true);
                            break;
                        } 
                    else{
                            tab.columns([9]).visible(false)
                            break;
                      `enter code here`  }
                    }
            }
```

**You can also use this condition this helps in checking condition after table data binding  processing complete.**

Comment: Its a good practice to leave a bit of explanation in your answer and not only code. Please edit your answer.